# Const class object with a pointer member

Tags: c++, class, constants, member-access

let's have an example program:

```
struct Example
{
    int* pointer;
    Example(int* p) : pointer(p) {}
};

int main()
{
    int var = 30;
    const Example object(&var);
    object.pointer = &var; // error
    *object.pointer = var;
}
```

I do know why the error appears - when creating a const `Example` object, `pointer` is actually const pointer, not a pointer to const. Therefore, when assigning `&var` to `object.pointer` it is not correct but assigning `var` to the `*object.pointer` works perfectly fine.
So is there any way to make this line:

```
*object.pointer = var;
```

not compile? I want the value that pointer points to to also be const. In other words, when creating a const object:

```
const Example object(&var);
```

I want constness to be applied also on the value itself, not only on the pointer:

```
const int* const pointer; // something like that
```

Comment: And what is the problem with this declaration const int* const pointer; or with this const int *pointer?

Comment: when `pointer` is `private` the line will fail to compile ;)

Answer (score 2):

Either declare the data member like

```
const int *pointer;
```

or make it a protected or private data member. In the last case you can declare a non-constant member function that allows to change the value pointed to by the pointer. For a constant object of the class the function will not be called. For example

```
struct Example
{
private:
    int* pointer;
public:
    Example(int* p) : pointer(p) {}
    int & get_value() { return *pointer; }
    const int & get_value() const { return *pointer; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const Example object(&var);
```

This creates a `const` object. Once a `const` object is created ***it cannot be changed***. This is what a constant object means, by definition.

```
object.pointer = &var;
```

This attempts to change this object's member. This object cannot be changed. It is a constant object now, hence the error.

> I want constness to be applied also on the value itself, not only on
> the pointer:
>
> ```
> const int* const pointer; // something like that
> ```

"Something like that" declares a `pointer` that's ***both*** a constant value itself, and it points to a constant value.

If you want an object with a pointer to `const int`, that would be:

```
const int *pointer;
```

And making the object ***itself*** constant has absolutely nothing to do with it, whatsoever. It only prevents modification of the object itself. Once you make something `const` ***it cannot be changed for any reason***.

Comment: This would not work because OP wants the constness to apply only for a `const Example` instance and not for a non-const one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that by

- Making `pointer` an member function that return the pointer
- Having non-const version of the function return a reference to the pointer to allow assignment to that
- Having const version of the function return a copy of the pointer to prevent assignment

```
struct Example
{
private:
    int* pointer_internal;
public:
    Example(int* p) : pointer_internal(p) {}
    int*& pointer() { return pointer_internal; }
    int* pointer() const { return pointer_internal; }
};

int main()
{
    int var = 30;
    const Example object(&var);
    object.pointer() = &var; // error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    *object.pointer() = var;
}
```